# GCD of two numbers in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a algorithm for the GCD of two numbers in a functional approach. Can this be improved further, also with regards to performance?

```
def gcd(a, b)
   return b if a ==0
   return a if b == 0
   return b if (a%b == 0)
   return a if (b%a == 0)
  (a > b)? gcd(a, a%b) : gcd(b%a, b)
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does not matter whether `a > b` or `b > a`, two cases should be enough for positive integers:

```
def gcd(a, b)
  b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a.modulo(b))
end
```

Check also [Integer#gcd](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-gcd).

Comment: What about the built-in [Integer#gdc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-gcd)? It's cheating, I know :)

Comment: By the way, maybe use `.zero?` instead of `== 0`? Either way is equally fine to my eyes, it's just to mention it

Comment: @Flambino: Good point, although I guess the OP knows about `Integer#gdc` and it's a pedagogical question. `b.zero?` would also look good, since I am already using `modulo` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def gcd a, b
  return a if b.zero?
  gcd b, a % b
end
```

Avoid `?:` when the `<return/next/break> if <condition>` form can be used.

Comment: This is a code dump with no explanation, and only mildly different from @tokland's answer.

Comment: @200_success I see nothing to add here. The question is too simple. The code is minimal.

Comment: I've added a one line of text to it. Totally pointless line. Because the code edit is trivial. It's just nothing to comment here. The answer was much clearer without this line.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: Stop the mindless comments spam cancer. My answers are explained enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with this one:

```rb
def gcd(a, b)
  a, b = b, a % b until b.zero?
  a
end
```

Comment: Please explain why this solution is better than the one posted in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].